# get result from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `orders` like this -

```
id  | bookId 
------------
1      3              
2      2               
3      1
```

and this `books` -

```
bookId  |  book
---------------
  1       bookA
  2       bookB
  3       bookC
```

is their any way i can get `book` column under `bookId` when i do

`select * from orders where id = '1'`

so that result would be like -

```
id  | bookId 
------------
1      bookC         <------- bookC instead of 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the tables on the `bookid` column in the `orders` table to the `bookid` column in the `books` table:

```
select o.id, b.book as bookId
from orders o
inner join books b
  on o.bookid = b.bookid
where o.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing a `JOIN`, to fetch the column under a different name you just need to say you want to get `b.book AS bookId`

```
SELECT o.id, b.book as bookId
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN books b
    ON o.bookId = b.id
WHERE o.id = 1
```

(Untested, the DBMS may complain about the similarity in column names)

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to what you're asking. The first is that you will need to perform a `JOIN` to get information from more than one table, according to some relationship between those tables (in this case, the relationship is defined by the shared `bookId` column).

Check out [this answer to a question about joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294854/2359271) for several references to help explain what a `JOIN` does. Other answers have already given you some code samples to work with, and for a basic tutorial there's always [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

The second part is that you want to return information from `books.book` but you don't want to call the column something other than `book`. So you have to use an alias, which is done very easily with the `AS` keyword (and this is also often used with `JOIN`). However, it's probably not a good idea to alias one column (`books.book`) by an existing name of another column (`orders.bookId`). The existing `bookId` column contains integers, not strings. It will be less confusing in the long run if you choose a more specific alias.

In order to use a column alias, you have to specifically refer to the column you want to alias in your `SELECT` statement. For instance: `SELECT book FROM books AS your_alias_here`.

Here's an example of a simple way to do what I think you want:

```
SELECT orders.id, books.book AS your_alias_here
FROM  orders INNER JOIN books USING(bookId)
```

Since `AS` follows `books.book`, the alias is applied to the `book` field from the `books` table.